# Django: Template {% url %} tag, how to pass parameter from form

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, button

There is template:

```
<form action="{% url 'nfoapp.views.kinoscrap' <I WANT MOVIE_ID THERE> selectshort.id %}" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MOVIE_ID">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Kinopoisk Search by ID</button>
</form>
```

There is my urls.py:

```
(r'^kinoscrap/(?P<kinoid>\d+)/(?P<shortid>\d+)/$', kinoscrap),
```

I want pass to `kinoscrap` two parameters - text field from form (MOVIE_ID) and 'selectshort.id' variable. The problem is that i can't put simple MOVIE_ID in first line of template, I got error. But when I try put instead MOVIE_ID other variable, for example `selectshort.id`, program work without error.

How I can trasmit text field value to view?

p.s I use bootstrap, if it has some importance.

Comment: Now I know - it's impossible. For now I transmit text field via request, and other parameters via named arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the form action empty, so to the same view, and then in the view redirect using the POST data from the form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MOVIE_ID">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Kinopoisk Search by ID</button>
</form>
```

And then in the view

```
def searchView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get variables from form and redirect
    else:
        # do your normal rendering
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(r'^kinoscrap/(?P<kinoid>\d+)/(?P<shortid>\d+)/$', kinoscrap),
```

Your urls.py accepts to integer values in the url (something like `kinnoscrap/12/21`), if you  pass anything beside integers it'll throw an error. If you want to pass a text field you'll have to change the regular expression.

Try out your regexes at [regex101](http://regex101.com) here to see if they'll work.